# Pod has been in Pending? Is it related to cni?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

centos7.5

Why is it always Pending here?Is the above etcd container not normal,Why isn’t the pod below?

To start K8S's own process, you also need to install the CNI container first.

```
[root@K8S-M1 ~]# kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
etcd-2               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}



[root@K8S-M1 ~]# kubectl get csr
NAME        AGE       REQUESTOR            CONDITION
csr-2bvfj   10h       system:node:K8S-M2   Pending
csr-48szz   10h       system:node:K8S-M1   Pending
csr-4lrzl   10h       system:node:K8S-M2   Pending
csr-4m9q9   10h       system:node:K8S-M3   Pending
csr-htwbq   10h       system:node:K8S-M3   Pending
csr-vb7hv   10h       system:node:K8S-M1   Pending
```

Resources should be sufficient

```
 [root@K8S-M1 ~]# df -Th
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs        50G  3.0G   47G   6% /
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G   50M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               xfs       797M  142M  656M  18% /boot
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2161c3bd3843566ad2188f02b6f21ea90fbda01606a465fdfa8c2a81a551a46c/merged
shm                     tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/b83ba180df8e29d815e140fb7b9974489a8b278af807ebe3c98a076f2291ee87/mounts/shm
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8400d260da55ae3db0235b2c1419fad5b8b190378f457dbd26119bf62e76b757/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf013d8436ee1bba4f6a6caeefbdf03a59f4af516e362889a6f913ff7360ec02/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e78e7ad517f52ef0c64887f110a128ec8d5afc0dca4a8b88b8ec56bec856b551/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6fda164d6535ee45623db59c447ad36590ec8b62a1bd1af8a9bd14f38d541d15/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/68f7325ae6bedddbac0838026e0984d1ce41c824a524fba54fdd2593858049dd/merged
shm                     tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/1b8fc403c9b2b123ceeb1d73da7787adacc05b58b45b6f522860c8fb81ff40aa/mounts/shm
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c2cdcbb4f36c8d9f55ba21b9c083b99eaae79cd34e4d22057d8f8da6475ab1ca/merged
shm                     tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/476fdf7fc04ba0cdb7aade7e6c0c9a5ebad41b95a9097717e848eb09b9d376ee/mounts/shm
shm                     tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/223ef9569f1cbd9005354d8b26991db506cf87c485ea170aae3dc97b3dde3861/mounts/shm
shm                     tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/2a09a1f72e8a7d67ac98e7699be06ef6dc8631b1c5db1994fe699394551855ec/mounts/shm
shm                     tmpfs      64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6219f8e9eacc22c5f5cce5b07c8d301b885df98c3174e3580ccd314a75e40e0e/mounts/shm
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe280abbe1f2d2fa0adcab938fa452af329511414b5a140cf28c78ea420b1e6d/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ee630697c9fbe93bccef86dfbac2e90644c2e9e4f28b7397fe474bbe2431951/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0b20400678fa4ccb05f2c27ee13161303b606871b0659a1b5774d271411ab552/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/acc4525beb65ae8a6f5793b2f0e65568f562b02c175ffbb19b4bd0b9dc385901/merged
overlay                 overlay    50G  3.0G   47G   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/876f125113a1b0d08ca3f7a80516d663b2e24a42afddfe69c6ba6cbb0754e29e/merged
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0


[root@K8S-M1 ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15883         690       14197          49         995       14648
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@K8S-M1 ~]# kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   FIRST SEEN   COUNT     NAME                      KIND      SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON                    SOURCE            MESSAGE
45m         1h           346       k8s-m1.1560d88dcc941af5   Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   kubelet, k8s-m1   Node k8s-m1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
13m         9h           7813      k8s-m3.1560bbb6ccbe5e13   Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   kubelet, k8s-m3   Node k8s-m3 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
8m          9h           7883      k8s-m2.1560bbb6c3dc7cdc   Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   kubelet, k8s-m2   Node k8s-m2 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
5m          1h           878       k8s-m1.1560d88dcc93e478   Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientDisk     kubelet, k8s-m1   Node k8s-m1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
3m          9h           7951      k8s-m2.1560bbb6c3dc2450   Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientDisk     kubelet, k8s-m2   Node k8s-m2 status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
3m          9h           7947      k8s-m3.1560bbb6ccbde61c   Node                  Normal    NodeHasSufficientDisk     kubelet, k8s-m3   Node k8s-m3 status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
```

Do you need to configure cni to start the system pod? I feel that I don't need this thing here

```
[root@K8S-M1 ~]# tail -f /var/log/messages
Oct 26 09:18:29 K8S-M1 kubelet: E1026 09:18:29.644297    1743 kubelet.go:2112] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Oct 26 09:18:32 K8S-M1 kubelet: I1026 09:18:32.511136    1743 kubelet_node_status.go:269] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Oct 26 09:18:33 K8S-M1 kubelet: E1026 09:18:33.861609    1743 eviction_manager.go:243] eviction manager: failed to get get summary stats: failed to get node info: node "k8s-m1" not found
Oct 26 09:18:34 K8S-M1 kubelet: W1026 09:18:34.645467    1743 cni.go:172] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Oct 26 09:18:34 K8S-M1 kubelet: E1026 09:18:34.645613    1743 kubelet.go:2112] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Oct 26 09:18:35 K8S-M1 kubelet: I1026 09:18:35.102542    1743 kubelet_node_status.go:269] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Oct 26 09:18:35 K8S-M1 kubelet: I1026 09:18:35.104947    1743 kubelet_node_status.go:79] Attempting to register node k8s-m1
Oct 26 09:18:35 K8S-M1 kubelet: E1026 09:18:35.107179    1743 kubelet_node_status.go:103] Unable to register node "k8s-m1" with API server: nodes "k8s-m1" is forbidden: node "K8S-M1" cannot modify node "k8s-m1"
Oct 26 09:18:39 K8S-M1 kubelet: W1026 09:18:39.646779    1743 cni.go:172] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Oct 26 09:18:39 K8S-M1 kubelet: E1026 09:18:39.646937    1743 kubelet.go:2112] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

[root@K8S-M1 ~]# cat  /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubelet.conf
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_SYSTEM_ARGS=--network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yml"
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-labels=node-role.kubernetes.io/master=''"
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

Comment: seems like resources cant be allocated , maybe not enough resources on the cluster

Comment: [root@K8S-M1 ~]#  kubectl get nodes
No resources found.
[root@K8S-M1 ~]#  kubectl -n kube-system get po
No resources found.

Comment: get nodes , no resurces found , should be fixed first

Comment: @ Ijaz Ahmad Khan   The above supplements the disk and memory resources, and the remaining resources are many.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start research with checking the core Kubernetes services residing on `kube-system` namespace:

`kubectl get all -n kube-system`

Of course, you can also retrieve health status for all available namespaces:

`kubectl get all --all-namespaces`

You can make the dump for each component in you cluster in order to investigate the cause of the problem:

`kubectl cluster-info dump --output-directory=<Output_directory>`

By default, its fetching the data from all namespaces across you cluster, where you can find separate log file for the particular K8s component.

It might be useful to review the general [Troubleshooting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/) Kubernetes cluster concepts in the official documentation.